# How to Deep Clone Doubly Linked List?

Tags: java, list, output, clone

I need to write a program that (implementing a doubly linked list):

- Prints out a list of the items in the list from front of the list to end of the list (this is my `toArrayFromFirst()` method)
- Prints out a list of the items in the list from the end of this to the front of the list (reverse order) (this is my `toArrayFromLast()` method)
- DeepClones the list (which is my `deepClone()` method)
- Prints out a list of the items in the copy of the list from front of the list to end of the list.

My issues:

- I think I'm getting code for a Singly Linked List and a Doubly Linked mixed up in my `deepClone()` method.
- My program is not outputting correctly, and I'm not sure if it's because I'm inserting elements into the list incorrectly, or if I'm displaying the list incorrectly, or if it's both.
- I'm getting this error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: DLL.DLL" (the error is in this line of code: `DLL<E> other = (DLL<E>)super.clone();` (in my `deepClone()` method)

This is what my code is currently outputting:

> List from first to last: Belgium Germany
>
> List from last to first: England Germany France Belgium

(And then I get an error right here when I try to deep clone the list)

This is what I want my code to output:

> List from first to last: Belgium France USA Germany England
>
> List from last to first: England Germany USA France Belgium
>
> Deep cloned list: Belgium France USA Germany England

Here is my DoublyLinkedList class:

```
package DLL;

public class DLL<E>
{
    private Node header = null;                         //header sentinel
    private Node trailer = null;                        //trailer sentinel
    private int size = 0;                               //number of elements in list

//nested Node class
private static class Node<E>
{   
    private E element;                              //reference to element stored at this node
    private Node prev;                              //reference to previous node in list
    private Node next;                              //reference to subsequent node in list

    public Node(E e)
    {
        element = e;
    }
    public E getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }       
    public Node<E> getPrev()
    {
        return prev;
    }
    public Node<E> getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    public void setPrev(Node<E> p)
    {
        prev = p;
    }
    public void setNext(Node<E> n)
    {
        next = n;
    }
    public void displayNode()
    {
        System.out.println(element + " "); 
    }
}

//returns number of elements in linked list
public int size()
{
    return size;
}

//tests whether linked list is empty
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return header == null;
}

//adds element e to front of list
public void addFirst(E e)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(e);

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        trailer = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        size++;
        header.prev = newNode;
        newNode.next = header;
    }
    header = newNode;
}

//adds element e to end of list
public void addLast(E e)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(e);

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        header = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        size++;
        trailer.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = trailer;
    }
    trailer = newNode;
}

//removes and returns first element of list
public Node removeFirst()
{
    Node temp = header;

    if (header.next == null)
    {
        trailer = null;
    }
    else
    {
        size--;
        header.next.prev = null;                    //null <-- old next
    }
    header = header.next;
    return temp;
}

//removes and returns last element of list
public Node removeLast()
{
    Node temp = trailer;

    if (header.next == null)
    {
        header = null;
    }
    else
    {
        size--;
        trailer.prev.next = null;                   //old prev --> null
    }
    trailer = trailer.prev;
    return temp;
}

//displays array of strings with elements in order from head to tail
    public void toArrayFromFirst()
    {
        System.out.println("List from first to last: ");
        Node current = header;

        while (current != null)
        {
            current.displayNode();
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    //displays array of strings with elements in order from tail to head
    public void toArrayFromLast()
    {
        System.out.println("List from last to first: ");
        Node current = trailer;

        while (current != null)
        {
            current.displayNode();
            current = current.prev;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    //displays cloned array with elements in order from head to tail
            public void clonedToArrayFromFirst()
            {
                System.out.println("Deep cloned list: ");
                Node current = header;

                while (current != null)
                {
                    current.displayNode();
                    current = current.next;
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

    //returns copy of list (deep clone)
    public DLL<E> deepClone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        DLL other = new DLL<E>();

        if (size > 0)
        {
            other.header = new Node<>(header.getElement());
            Node<E> walk = header.getNext();
            Node<E> otherTrailer = other.header;

            while (walk != null)
            {
                Node<E> newest = new Node<>(walk.getElement());
                otherTrailer.setNext(newest);
                otherTrailer = newest;
                walk = walk.getNext();
            }
        }
        return other;
    }
```

}

And here is my main():

```
package DLL;

public class DLLTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException 
    {
        DLL myList = new DLL();
        DLL clonedList = new DLL();

        myList.addFirst("USA");
        myList.addLast("Germany");
        myList.addFirst("France");
        myList.addLast("England");
        myList.addFirst("Belgium");

        myList.toArrayFromFirst();
        myList.toArrayFromLast();

        clonedList = myList.deepClone();
        clonedList.clonedToArrayFromFirst();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try to search for the error message on internet?

Comment: @MiserableVariable, I have not searched for the error message specifically on the internet. I have, however, looked at several examples of deep cloning and outputting of doubly linked lists, but I am still not sure what is wrong with my code.

Comment: You have an issue in your addFirst() method. You aren't setting the header in it. That should solve your problem, or most of it anyway.

Comment: Why do you pass the second argument to `Node` since it is always null and you don't even use it in your constructor?

Comment: @Bifz - I'm actually not sure why I did that. I have been looking at a lot of examples, so I'm sure one of them had two arguments passed into Node and then I probably passed in null each time I called the method just to make arguments match. (I'm awful at programming) But, even when I remove the second argument in all instances, I still have the same null pointer exception that I listed in a comment below (in response to Jason)

Comment: @Jaydelay Yah, the second argument doesn't change your program behaviour whatsoever. It was just there doing nothing or annoying your constructor calls.
Check my answer, your code has several problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using more than once these two lines together in your loops:

```
current = current.getNext();
current = current.next;
```

Beside that, you're not updating your DLL size anywhere. So your `deepClone` doesn't even enter your condition `if (size > 0)`.

Lastly, instead of using `super.clone()` just create a new DLL and add your values.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I edited the code to exactly what you suggested, and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I spotted a problem in `addFirst()`. You should always be setting the header:

```
//adds element e to front of list
public void addFirst(E e)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(e, null);

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        trailer = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        header.prev = newNode;
        newNode.next = header;
    }
    header = newNode;
}
```

Comment: thank you for catching that. It was a careless mistake on my part. I have updated the code per your suggestion. Now I am getting a null pointer exception in my line of code: `private Node next;` in my private static class Node<E>